# Why doesn't rpcinfo command in linux show rabbitmq?

Tags: openstack, rabbitmq, rpc, amqp

What I understood is that some of the Openstack components communicate using RabbitMQ service (which uses RPC protocol) while other communicate using REST APIs, DB queries etc.

But when I check rpcinfo -p, it doesn't list any service related to RabbitMQ/openstack.

What's the difference between the communication mechanism of services which are dispayed in rpcinfo (Eg: NIS, NFS etc.) and RabbitMQ/Openstack service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RPC stands for `remote procedure call`. The main problem with it is that there are too many protocols that called `RPC`. The one which is used by NIS and NFS is know as ONC RPC (or SUN RPC). Openstack used another RPC implementation - based on [AMQP](https://www.amqp.org/), which is incompatible with oncrpc. As a result, you need a different tools to inspect and monitor. You can start from [RabbitMQ monitoring](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#http-api)